# Mongodb not working on Ubuntu -> mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I installed mongodb following this tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04), no errors during the installation but when I try to start the mongod server using this command `sudo systemctl start mongodb` as the tutorial mentions, i getting this error when i try to check whether it is running using this command `sudo systemctl status mongodb`.

```
● mongodb.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented 

database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: 
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Rab 2016-06-01 18:04:20 MYT; 4s ago
  Process: 8241 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf (cod
 Main PID: 8241 (code=exited, status=14)

Jun 01 18:04:20 yasinya systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free docume
Jun 01 18:04:20 yasinya systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=e
Jun 01 18:04:20 yasinya systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 01 18:04:20 yasinya systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-co
lines 1-10/10 (END)
```

so can anyone tell what is wrong and how I can fix it.

Comment: Check out the answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/767934/mongdb-installation-failed-on-ubuntu-16-04/767965#767965), which may help you.

Comment: ok let me try that thanks

Comment: @titi23 i got an error `Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found`

Comment: [this link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/690993/mongodb-3-0-2-wont-start-after-upgrading-to-ubuntu-15-10) may be having the solution. Try searching with the error you are getting. You will get some solution.

Comment: If you were running a mongodb server and updated the system, chances are it has the “old” lock file: you can try removing it (in Ubuntu: `/var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock`) and trying then `systemctl start mongodb.service`

Answer (score 51):

Recently i have solved the same issue. I was unable to find the solution on googled, but i get come clues to, how get figure it out. In my case this issue was related to mongodb-27017.sock file.

```
Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock errno:1 Operation not permitted
```

So i have changed the permission of /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock file to default `mongodb` user.

```
sudo chown mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
sudo chgrp mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

After this `sudo systemctl status mongodb` working fine and `mongodb` is started.

Comment: Thank you so much. It helps me!

Comment: same happen with /var/lib/mongodb and /var/log/mongodb

Comment: After applying your solution I am getting error -  `Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.` any idea why?

Comment: a shorter one-liner with the same result would be `sudo chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock`.

Answer (score 36):

Stumbed on the same issue, just reboot

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: saved my day.. !

Comment: Wow, this is quite interesting.

Comment: This is a persistent problem, the solution works but we can't reboot all the time in production environment...

Comment: well done, that was the way to solve the problem

Comment: mine on Manjaro was also fixed by rebooting

Answer (score 32):

This error returned by MongoDB applications which encounter an unrecoverable error, an uncaught exception or uncaught signal. The system exits without performing a clean shutdown.

I solved the problem by the command:

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/lib/mongodb
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/log/mongodb

sudo chown mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
sudo chgrp mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Then restart service

```
sudo systemctl restart mongod
```

Then check your mongodb service

```
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

Comment: Solved for me! Thanx

Comment: You are a legend bro.Thanks for saving my day

Comment: Thanks. Was finally able to get the DB up.

Comment: Thank goodness. Didn't have *.sock files, but the first 4 commands fixed it! 

Comment: This didn't solve the issue for me

Comment: Maybe your disk space was full you can check it by df -i , anyway you can check mongodb log file in var/log/mongodb to clearify your server problem

Answer (score 10):

I had same use ,

get solve just

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: This is the main reason , don't do anything , Just reboot

Answer (score 6):

The first thing, you should examine the mongo log. It should tell you what went wrong.

`$ tail -n 100 /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`

This command will show last 100 lines of the log file which will point you to the exact problem.

For example, mine wasn't working because i was running a `mongo` instance using the same port `27017`. when i ran another instance, the instance failed to load.

### LOG

```
2018-05-11T19:03:49.102-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1247 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=dev-hyuen
2018-05-11T19:03:49.103-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.20
2018-05-11T19:03:49.103-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: a7a144f40b70bfe290906eb33ff2714933544af8
2018-05-11T19:03:49.103-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2018-05-11T19:03:49.103-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2018-05-11T19:03:49.103-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2018-05-11T19:03:49.103-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2018-05-11T19:03:49.103-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2018-05-11T19:03:49.103-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2018-05-11T19:03:49.103-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2018-05-11T19:03:49.103-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log", quiet: true } }
2018-05-11T19:03:49.124-0400 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 127.0.0.1:27017
2018-05-11T19:03:49.124-0400 E NETWORK  [initandlisten]   addr already in use
2018-05-11T19:03:49.124-0400 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up sockets during startup.
2018-05-11T19:03:49.124-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 48
```

Comment: this answer cover most of the cases, running tail command on mongo db log file will show exactly what went wrong, and we can debug from there.

Answer (score 6):

Step1. `sudo systemctl stop mongodb`

Step2. `sudo systemctl start mongod`

Step3. `sudo systemctl status mongod`

I hope it helps you

[image]

Answer (score 3):

#### Case with me:

1. I installed mongodb from [official site](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).
2. Worked fine after installation, even worked with **command-line**, **Robo3T** and **Compass**.
3. Problems occurred after rebooting once.

*So, I checked the status*

```
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

and got this:-

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2021-02-20 18:11:19 IST; 5s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 724411 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 724411 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 20 18:11:18 bunty systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Feb 20 18:11:19 bunty mongod[724411]: {"t":{"$date":"2021-02-20T12:41:19.657Z"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":>
Feb 20 18:11:19 bunty systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 20 18:11:19 bunty systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

*If your case is similar...*

#### How I solved it?

1. Check if these two directories exists or not: `/var/lib/mongodb` and `/var/log/mongodb`.

You can do this with:

```
test -d /var/lib/mongodb && echo "Directory Exists"
test -d /var/log/mongodb && echo "Directory Exists"
```

2. The one which does not exist, make it with `mkdir` command.

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/mongodb # run only if it does not exist
sudo mkdir /var/log/mongodb # run only if it does not exist
```

3. Change owners of these directories to `mongodb`. Do this for both the directories.

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb 
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb
```

4. Restart the mongod server.

```
sudo systemctl restart mongod
```

5. Let's check.

```
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

If output is something like

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-02-20 18:15:01 IST; 59min ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
   Main PID: 734383 (mongod)
     Memory: 166.7M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mongod.service
             └─734383 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf

Feb 20 18:15:01 bunty systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
```

you are good to go.

For mongo shell:

```
mongo
```

This works for me every time `mongod` fails, hope it works for you too.

Namaste

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the similar error, in my case mongo couldn't use 27017.
I needed to stop whatever was using 27017 port and restart mongo.

Answer (score 1):

because the permission setting

```
chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

if this worked for me after reinstalling mongodb. I have created manually

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/mongodb
sudo mkdir /var/log/mongodb
```

and changed owner for both

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be related to the lack of space with your `/dev/root/` (it was mine).

Check with `df -h` and see if there enough free space.
Otherwise, as explain [there](https://askubuntu.com/a/220663/667150), try to free some space by moving the log files to another disk.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/rsyslog stop
sudo mv /var/log /OTHERDISK/
sudo ln -s /OTHERDISK/log /var/log
sudo /etc/init.d/rsyslog start
```

Hope it could help as it helps me

Answer (score 0):

After googling around for a while. I found that that is because the permission setting on 
/var/lib/mongodb and /tmp/mongodb-27017.lock are wrong. You will have to change the owner to monogdb user

```
chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, increasing `ulimit` value for number of open files, solved my problem.

Like in the [MongoDB docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#run-mongodb-community-edition) note, if you execute ulimit -n command and the result is lower than 64000. Just execute this command: `ulimit -n 128000`. By the way 128000 is not a specific number. I made it up.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS.

After trying all of the above that didn't work.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall mongodb
```

Reinstalling it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

In my case the system was not able to to find mongod.service 
**Running the following command will fixed it**

```
sudo systemct1 enable mongod
```

then restart the database by

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

Comment: `sudo systemctl enable mongod`