# Mongodb - how to restart mongodb that you just killed in Linux?

Tags: linux, mongodb

How can I restart mongodb that I just killed in Linux?

Before killing:

```
$ service mongodb status
● mongodb.service - An object/document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2017-01-03 08:41:16 GMT; 4h 5min ago
     Docs: man:mongod(1)
 Main PID: 1036 (mongod)
    Tasks: 10
   Memory: 61.0M
      CPU: 1min 1.636s
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongodb.service
           └─1036 /usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf
```

So I wanted to stop/ kill it for a while for other programs:

```
$ sudo kill 1036
$ service mongodb status
● mongodb.service - An object/document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:mongod(1)
```

But how can I start it again?

I'm on Ubuntu **16.04.**

**EDIT:**

```
$ systemctl start mongod 
Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
Get this error below when I have the other program running on mondodb. so I killed that program and it works as before.

$ sudo systemctl start mongodb
$ service mongodb status
● mongodb.service - An object/document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongodb.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-01-03 13:05:19 GMT; 9s ago
     Docs: man:mongod(1)
  Process: 21732 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongodb.conf (code=exited, status=48)
 Main PID: 21732 (code=exited, status=48)
```

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

```
sudo systemctl start mongodb
```

Not only for MongoDB, but for any application installed, you can use

```
sudo systemctl start <app_name>
sudo systemctl restart <app_name>
```

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565758/mongodb-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: thanks. how can i stop mongo correctly? I tried with `$ sudo systemctl stop mongod` then I get this error `Failed to stop mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not loaded.`

Comment: the service is mongodb.service,  so you need start/ stop mongodb, not mongod

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you are using `systemd`.

Try:

- `systemctl start mongod`   => Start the the service
- `systemctl status mongod`  => Status of the service
- `systemctl restart mongod` => restart the service
- `systemctl reload mongod`  => reload the service

Comment: how can i stop mongo correctly? I tried with `$ sudo systemctl stop mongod` then I get this error `Failed to stop mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not loaded.`

Comment: @teelou systemctl stop mongod...The error says that your mongod is either not running or it is already stopped. This works for me in Ubuntu 16.04, verified it just now

Answer (score 2):

You checked status with :

```
service mongod status
```

so this should start mongod:

```
service mongod start
```

so this should stop mongod:

```
sudo service mongod stop
```

It works at my end.
for missing permissions:

```
sudo service mongod start
```

Comment: I tried that before but getting this error `Failed to stop mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not loaded.`

Comment: chk this  [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/770054/mongodb-3-2-doesnt-start-on-lubuntu-16-04-lts-as-a-service)