# Always get "Active: failed" on 'sudo systemctl status mongod' command

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, systemctl

I followed [this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04) to install MongoDB on my machine. Everything was fine and it worked.
Currently, when I run `sudo systemctl status mongod`, I get this error:

```sh
● mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since سه<U+200C>شنبه 2019-05-21 15:50:14 +0430; 25min ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 5278 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 5278 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

مه 21 15:50:14 [my-username] systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
مه 21 15:50:14 [my-username] systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
مه 21 15:50:14 [my-username] systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.
مه 21 15:50:14 [my-username] systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

This is what I have done after it was ok, that might have caused the problem:

- I decided to add mongodb extension using `pecl`.
  I was not able to make a new database, neither by MongodDB Compassm, nor by Sell.
- I uninstalled it.
- I installed it from the same link and ran the same commands, but when I wanted to install it again, after running `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6`
   command, I got `gpg: unchanged: 1` at the end, not `gpg: imported: 1  (RSA: 1)` which I got for the first time.
- I even deleted and recreated my `dbPath` folder (`/var/lib/mongodb`) which seems that the problem is somehow associated with this parameter which is on `/etc/mongod.conf`.

When I run `sudo systemctl status mongod`, I still get `Active: failed`.

What should I do to run MongoDB properly again and make its status `Active: Running`?

**Update**: This is my `/etc/mongod.conf` file:

```sh
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


#processManagement:

security:
  authorization: "enabled"

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Comment: Can you please add more of what `journalctl -u mongodb` shows?

Comment: It returns `-- No entries --`.

Comment: Have you tried starting it using `sudo systemctl start mongodb`? I don't see that you tried to start in manually, just reinstalling etc. Probably you have restarted your machine after the first installation?

Comment: Yes, I did it like 10 times.

Comment: Did you make data/db/ directory using sudo mkdir -p /data/db ? Also can you post your mongod.conf file? Maybe also do a sudo apt update then sudo apt install -y mongodb and then see if your sudo systemctl status mongodb command works

Comment: I faced all those solutions during my searches and they did not work for me. I update my question with `mongod.conf` file.

Comment: I think it looks okay your .conf file unless I'm missing something and what is the exact error when you enter systemctl start mongod .. Have you tried just a sudo reboot as listed here and the other thing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565758/mongodb-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: I faced this post on my searches, but I do not have `mongodb-27017.sock` on my `/tmp/` directory. I did tried rebooting multiple times.

Comment: What if you update in your /etc/mongod.conf the line where it says   dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb too
dbPath: /data/db

Comment: Nah, didn't work.

Comment: What is the output of the following ? sudo service mongod start.. Also it may be good to follow official MongoDB docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Also in the tutorial it says to be using Ubuntu Server are you using that or Ubuntu Dekstop? Make sure you adhere to the prereqs

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I did exactly whatever you mentioned in your answers, before asking this question.

Comment: All right the last thing I can think of is just uninstalling it and reinstalling it again. Sorry I couldn't help

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by uninstalling MongoDB and installing a specific version of MongoDB, not the latest version, [using this link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/). This might not be the actual solution but works for now.