# mongod.service active : failed (failed to start mongodb server)

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I just started learning mongodb everything was going well until I tried stoping the server using `sudo systemctl stop mongod` and restarting it using`sudo systemctl start mongod`.
now its showing:-

```
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2021-01-16 12:39:04 IST; 3s ago
       Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
    Process: 357998 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 357998 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 16 12:39:04 prabal-computer systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database Server.
Jan 16 12:39:04 prabal-computer mongod[357998]: {"t":{"$date":"2021-01-16T07:09:04.669Z"},"s":"F",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20574,   "ctx":"main">
Jan 16 12:39:04 prabal-computer systemd[1]: mongod.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 16 12:39:04 prabal-computer systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
lines 1-11/11 (END)
```

whenever I am trying to start and see the status using `sudo systemctl status mongod`,this error appears.

note: I have already tried reinstalling the mongodb

Comment: add some more details like jurnalctl -u mongod , tail /var/log/mongo.log  and /etc/mongod.conf

Comment: check here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37565758/mongodb-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Check out the mongod log file. Most likely the dbPath does not exist.